# OpenRefine - combining rows into one record

Tags: python, jython, data-cleaning, openrefine, grel

I have a dataset with records that have been split across multiple rows. Is there an easy way to combine these values into one row?

[image: screenshot of dataset]

The screenshot shows what I have at present. The ID column has the same value, but the dates have been scattered across different rows. I want to have these all on just one row.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that the ID column is already sorted and it is the first column.

If this is the case you can create [records](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exploring#rows-vs-records) by using [Edit cells => Blank down](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#fill-down-and-blank-down) on your ID column.

After switching to "record mode" (see the [interface description](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/running#the-project-screen)) you can use [Edit cells => Join multi-valued cells...](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#join-multi-valued-cells) on each date column.